# Well-posed problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition, physics

In the definition of a well-posed problem it states that a problem is well posed if:

1.A solution exists.
2.The solution is unique.
3.The solution's behaviour changes continuously with the initial conditions.

Could someone explain how to interpret condition 3.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 2):

Small deviations at the input should cause only small deviations at the output.

Comment: What are considered small deviations?

Comment: That depends on the problem! If $D$ is the data and $S$ is the solution, you might for example get inequalities of the type $\|\delta S\|\le\text{constant}\cdot\|\delta D\|$, where the two $\|\cdot\|$ are suitable norms, and $\delta$ stands for “deviation of …”. But *which* norms will usually depend on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are solving the heat equation on a thin metal rod (a 1D PDE). Imagine some initial temperature distribution $T_{1}(x,t=0)$ on the rod. That's your initial condition, and the heat equation will govern the time evolution of the temperature distribution on that rod: $T_{1}(x,t)$. Now imagine that, instead of that temperature distribution as your initial condition, you raise the initial temperature uniformly by some small amount $dT$: $T_{2}(x,t=0)=T_1(x,t=0)+dT$. The solution to the heat equation (its time evolution) should not change substantially (i.e. hit a singularity) as you *slowly* vary the inputs: $T_{2}(x,t) \sim T_{1}(x,t) + F(x,t,T) \;dT$, where $F(x,t,T)$ is continuously differentiable.

If instead you made a small change to the initial condition and the solution (evolution in time) suddenly blew up or changed in a significant way, then something went wrong: your problem was not well-posed to begin with.